# Unable to rotate an SCNNode in ARKit

Tags: swift, transform, scenekit, arkit

I'm trying to rotate an SCNNode on the y-axis so my node (an arrow) points in the right direction. I want to make a navigation app that uses ARKit; each arrow needs to point to the next location of the route I have received. The retrieval of the route works properly.

The nodes are added to the rootNode of the scene. At some point I traverse an array of nodes to position them in the scene and apply scaling to the node (based on the distance), which is all done correctly. However, when I apply rotation, this has no effect.
The rotation is done by modifying the rotation property of the node:

```
directionNode.rotation = SCNVector4(x:0, y:1:, z:0, w:Float(bearing))
```

This does not have the desired effect.
I also tried to use the runAction method, also no effect:

```
directionNode.runAction(SCNAction.rotateBy(x: 0, y: CGFloat(bearing), z: 0, duration: 0))
```

Here's the code that positions and scales the nodes.

```
for i in 0...(directionNodes.count - 1) {

    let directionNode = directionNodes[i]
    let translation = MatrixHelper.transformMatrix(for: matrix_identity_float4x4, 
                                        originLocation: startingLocation, 
                                              location: directionNode.location)
    let position = SCNVector3.positionFromTransform(translation)
    let distance = directionNode.location.distance(from: startingLocation)

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let scale = 100 / Float(distance)
        directionNode.scale = SCNVector3(x: scale, y: scale, z: scale)
        directionNode.anchor = ARAnchor(transform: translation)
        directionNode.position = position

        if (i < (self.directionNodes.count - 1)) {
            // Apply rotation to the arrow
            let successiveStepLocation = self.directionNodes[i + 1].location!
            let bearing = directionNode.location.bearingToLocationRadian(successiveStepLocation)
            // rotate
            directionNode.rotation = SCNVector4(x:0, y:1:, z:0, w:Float(bearing))
        }
    }
}
```

This is all wrapped in a SCNTransaction.

Can anyone tell me why the rotation of the node is not working? Any help is greatly appreciated.

**[EDIT]**: I forgot to mention that the 3D arrow object that I'm trying to rotate always points in the same direction. Even when I 'walk around' it the arrow always points (in my case) to the left.
Maybe this helps solving my issue...

Answer (score 1):

> **Update:** I reckon the problem is in `singleSided` shader you're using. You see the invisible side of your model. Just enable **`doubleSided`** material for your geometry:

```
directionNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true
```

You need to use values expressed in Radians (effective range is `-6.28` to `+6.28`).

> It's important in what direction your object is rotated >> `CW` or `CCW`. You can't see the `single-sided` geometry (***at a certain angle***) at a positive angle of rotation `+.pi`.

It works this way:

```
myNode.rotation = SCNVector4(x: 0, y: -1, z: 0, w: (.pi * 3) / 2)
```

...and when you're using SCNAction, too (and don't forget to assign a duration):

```
let action = SCNAction.repeatForever(SCNAction.rotate(by: -.pi, 
                                                  around: SCNVector3(0,1,0), 
                                                duration: 1.75))
myNode.runAction(action)
```

...and when you're using SCNTransaction, too:

```
let previousTransform = myNode.transform
let rotate = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(0, 1, 0, (-Float.pi/2))

SCNTransaction.begin()
SCNTransaction.animationDuration = 3.75
myNode.transform = SCNMatrix4Mult(rotate, previousTransform)
SCNTransaction.commit()
```

[image]

Comment: For bearing I get different values, like -1.70 or 3.09
I tried to apply the rotation like the example above, but no results. I also tried to rotate on a different axis, still no results.

What I also added is a hover (up and down movement) to the nodes. That does work, but somehow the rotation is 'blocked'.

Comment: Could you publish all the code to see what's going on there?

Comment: When the geometry of the node returns nil, what does that mean? I can see the object in the scene though.

Comment: Nope. If geometry returns `nil` there's no geometry to watch at. It might be due to anchors or due to absence of geometry.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for the answer, helped me a lot in understanding the different ways of rotation.

However, it turns out there was a constraint on the node like this:

```
let billboardConstraint = SCNBillboardConstraint()
billboardConstraint.freeAxes = SCNBillboardAxis.Y
constraints = [billboardConstraint]
```

Commenting this code made the rotation work properly. Pretty dumb...

According to the documentation a SCNBillboardConstraint makes the object's z-axis always point towards the `pointOfView` node. But I do not quite understand the freeAxes property here. The default type is `all`, so it never rotates with respect to the point of view. So if I only set the Y constraint type, I can only apply rotation on the X and Z axes? Or am I wrong here?