# ARKit cannot rotate a SCNNode correctly on a vertical plane

Tags: swift, rotation, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

I want to rotate a SCNNode, which is a painting image.

I can rotate it on the floor, but I cannot rotate it correctly on wall.

(I am using UIRotationGestureRecognizer)

```
...
  func addPainting(_ hitResult: ARHitTestResult, _ grid: Grid) {

    ...

    // Add the painting
    let newPaintingNode = SCNNode(geometry: planeGeometry)
    newPaintingNode.transform = SCNMatrix4(hitResult.anchor!.transform)
    newPaintingNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3(newPaintingNode.eulerAngles.x + (-Float.pi / 2), newPaintingNode.eulerAngles.y, newPaintingNode.eulerAngles.z)
    newPaintingNode.position = SCNVector3(hitResult.worldTransform.columns.3.x, hitResult.worldTransform.columns.3.y, hitResult.worldTransform.columns.3.z)
    self.paintingNode = newPaintingNode

    self.currentAngleY = newPaintingNode.eulerAngles.y
    self.currentAngleZ = newPaintingNode.eulerAngles.z

    augmentedRealityView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(self.paintingNode!)
    grid.removeFromParentNode()
  }
...

  @objc func rotateNode(_ gesture: UIRotationGestureRecognizer){

    if let currentNode = self.paintingNode {
      //1. Get The Current Rotation From The Gesture
      let rotation = Float(gesture.rotation)

      if self.paintingAlignment == "horizontal" {

        log.verbose("rotate horizontal!")

        //2. If The Gesture State Has Changed Set The Nodes EulerAngles.y
        if gesture.state == .changed {
          currentNode.eulerAngles.y = currentAngleY + rotation
        }

        //3. If The Gesture Has Ended Store The Last Angle Of The Cube
        if(gesture.state == .ended) {
          currentAngleY = currentNode.eulerAngles.y
        }

      } else if self.paintingAlignment == "vertical" {

        log.verbose("rotate vertical!")

        //2. If The Gesture State Has Changed Set The Nodes EulerAngles.z
        if gesture.state == .changed {
          currentNode.eulerAngles.z = currentAngleZ + rotation
        }

        //3. If The Gesture Has Ended Store The Last Angle Of The Cube
        if(gesture.state == .ended) {
          currentAngleZ = currentNode.eulerAngles.z
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

[image]

Does anyone know how can I rotate it correctly on wall? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried `SCNNode eulerAngles` and `SCNNode rotation` and I have no luck...

I guess that is because I invoked `SCNNode.transform()` when I add the painting. When later I modify `SCNNode.eulerAngles` and invoke `SCNNode.rotation()`, they may have influence on the first `transform`.

I finally get it working using `SCNMatrix4Rotate`, not using `eulerAngles` and `rotation`.

```
  func addPainting(_ hitResult: ARHitTestResult, _ grid: Grid) {
    ...
    let newPaintingNode = SCNNode(geometry: planeGeometry)
    newPaintingNode.transform = SCNMatrix4(hitResult.anchor!.transform)
    newPaintingNode.transform = SCNMatrix4Rotate(newPaintingNode.transform, -Float.pi / 2.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    newPaintingNode.position = SCNVector3(hitResult.worldTransform.columns.3.x, hitResult.worldTransform.columns.3.y, hitResult.worldTransform.columns.3.z)
    self.paintingNode = newPaintingNode
    ...
  }
...
  @objc func rotateNode(_ gesture: UIRotationGestureRecognizer){

    if let _ = self.paintingNode {

      // Get The Current Rotation From The Gesture
      let rotation = Float(gesture.rotation)

      if gesture.state == .began {
        self.rotationZ = rotation
      }

      if gesture.state == .changed {
        let diff = rotation - self.rotationZ
        self.paintingNode?.transform = SCNMatrix4Rotate(self.paintingNode!.transform, diff, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        self.rotationZ = rotation
      }

    }

  }
```

And the above code works on both vertical and horizontal plane.

Answer (score 2):

You're using `eulerAngles` instance property in your code:

```
var eulerAngles: SCNVector3 { get set }
```

According to Apple documentation:

> SceneKit applies `eulerAngles` rotations relative to the node’s pivot property in the reverse order of the components: first `roll` (**Z**), then `yaw` (**Y**), then `pitch` (**X**).

### ...but three-component rotation can lead to [Gimbal Lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock).

> Gimbal lock is the loss of one degree of freedom in a three-dimensional, three-gimbal mechanism that occurs when the axes of two of the three gimbals are driven into a parallel configuration, "locking" the system into rotation in a degenerate two-dimensional space.

So you need to use a four-component rotation property:

```
var rotation: SCNVector4 { get set }
```

> The **[four-component rotation vector](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1408034-rotation)** specifies the direction of the rotation axis in the first three components (**XYZ**) and the angle of rotation, expressed in `radians`, in the fourth (**W**).

```
currentNode.rotation = SCNVector4(x: 1, 
                                  y: 0, 
                                  z: 0,
                                  w: -Float.pi / 2)
```

If you want to know more about `SCNVector4` structure and four-component rotation (and its W component expressed in radians) look at **[THIS POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50997832/scnnode-z-rotation-axis-stays-constant-while-x-and-y-axes-change-when-node-is-r/50999493#50999493)** and **[THIS POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55972326/unable-to-rotate-an-scnnode-in-arkit/55972758#55972758)**.

**P.S.**

In **RealityKit** framework instead of `SCNVector4` structure you need to use `SIMD4<Float>` generic structure or `simd_float4` type alias.

```
var rotation: simd_float4 { get set }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I try to use SCNVector4, but the outcome is still weird. Sometime it works properly and sometime it doesn't. I changed the `rotateNode()` and added `self.paintingNode?.rotation = SCNVector4(x: 0, y: 0, z: 1, w: currentAngleZ + rotation)` when `self.paintingAlignment == "vertical"`.

Comment: Is your `W` value in radians or in degrees? Are you using `local` axis or `world` axis when making rotation? And consider that positive `Z` value is for Counter-Clock-Wise rotation (`CCW`), and negative `Z` value is for Clock-Wise rotation (`CW`).

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the late reply. My `w` value is in radians. I have no idea whether I am using `local` axis or `world` axis...